# Can't init bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, vue.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I can't get bootstrap-datepicker (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) to initialize the proper way or call any methods or events on it.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.7 / Vue 2.3.3 / jQuery 3.1.0

My html look like this:

`<input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" />`

But when I try to initialize the datepicker using the "official" way it doesn't set any of the properties (no errors either):

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true
    });
```

It doesn't matter where I place the code (beginning, end, vue created-method, vue mounted-method, $nextTick).

However setting the values like this works:

`$.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayHighlight = true;`

Unfortunately since non of the other methods or events seem to work either just using the `$.fn.datepicker.defaults` is not enough.

Does anyone have a clue on what might be wrong?

Comment: did you added jQuery library before your datepicker library?

Comment: Add `class = "datepicker"` in your input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `input` field code to this:

`<input type="text" data-provider="datepicker" class="datepicker" />`

The issue was of CSS selector i.e. you were searching for an element with `datepicker` class but their was no such element.

So just add the class attribute to it.

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked this.. the doc is a bit incosistent with it's examples. I assumed the `data-provider="datepicker"` tag would be enough.

Comment: @ArnovanOordt You could use `$('[data-provide="datepicker"]')` if you want to use that instead of a class name.

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, but the jQuery code was using the class selector, so adding a class attribute is more easy in this case